# getting undefined method `click_button' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

For selecting dropdown   using capybara : getting undefined method

`click_button' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)       ./features/pages/cm_dash_board.rb:187:in`choose_role'       ./features/pages/cm_dash_board.rb:147:in `set_role'       ./features/step_definitions/cm_dash_board_steps.rb:58:in`/^

```
Method:
  def choose_role(role_name)
    click_button CHOOSE_ROLE
    find(ROLEDROPDOWN).all('li').select{|role| role.text == role_name}.first.click_button 
  end 
Feature file:And(/^I assign "([^"]*)" role to the "([^"]*)" user$/) do |email, role_name|
  @sw.cm_dash_board.set_role(email,role_name)
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That error tells you that `find(ROLEDROPDOWN).all('li').select{|role| role.text == role_name}` isn't matching any elements.  The first `find` is finding something (or you'd have a different error), but then either `all('li')` is finding no elements or the select is filtering out all elements.

As a side node, you really shouldn't be using `select` for this anyway and should instead be specifying it in your `all` call like

```
find(ROLEDROPDOWN).find('li', exact_text: role_name).click_button
```

That may well still fail, but at least the error will tell you why it's failing